# Google Analytics not showing any data

Tags: ionic-framework, google-analytics, ionic3

After building a basic ionic 3 app with two pages (quotes-list and quotes-detail) where clicking a name on the former you edit a text on the latter, run the app on a real device and go through GA, trying to get some statistics about the two tracked pages, but all I can see is nothing. Anyone could help me, please? I'm not able to get data, neither past nor real time. I'd appreciate it so much...

app.module.ts

```js
import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/google-analytics';

  providers: [
    GoogleAnalytics,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/google-analytics';

export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = QuotesListPage;
  
  constructor(platform: Platform, googleanalytics: GoogleAnalytics) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      googleanalytics.debugMode();      
      googleanalytics.startTrackerWithId("UA-XXXXXXXXX-1");
      googleanalytics.enableUncaughtExceptionReporting(true).then((_success) => {
        console.log("Successful enabling of uncaught exception reporting "+_success)}).catch((_error) => {
          console.log("error occured "+_error)
      });
    });
  }  
  
}
```

quotes-list.ts

```js
  

  import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/google-analytics';        
    
  constructor(platform: Platform, private http:Http, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public googleanalytics: GoogleAnalytics) {
    this.isfiltered = false;
    this.http.get('quotes.json')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.quotesList = data.quotes;
      },
      err => console.log("error is "+err), // error
      () => console.log('read quotes Complete '+ this.quotesList) // complete
    );    
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      googleanalytics.trackView("Quotes List"); 
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {            
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad QuotesListPage');
  }      

}
```

quotes-detail.ts

```js
  import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/google-analytics';
  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public googleanalytics: GoogleAnalytics) {
   this.quoteDetail = navParams.get('quote');   
   googleanalytics.trackView("Quotes Detail");     
  }      

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 changes needed in app.components.ts

1. Ensure `googleanalytics.startTrackerWithId("UA-XXXXXXXXX-1");` is always the first line to be executed before any other analytics code.
2. Remove `googleanalytics.debugMode();`

Comment: for me  googleanalytics.startTrackerWithId("UA-XXXXXXXXX-1"); returing null i success call back...ny suggestions

Comment: Is the plugin properly installed ?